# refresh textbox when powerpoint slide is shown

Tags: sql-server, vba, powerpoint

I'm using PowerPoint 2016 for a Wallboard display and I'd like it to pull a number from an MSSQL-Server table. I can get the SQL data into Powerpoint easily enough but I would like the data to refresh every day automatically and leave the wallboard running continuously.

I have a textbox on a slide that pulls data from an SQL VBA script. Is there a way to automatically run the script each time the slide is shown while the presentation is running or have the script run once every 24 hours to refresh the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky and interesting problem and I'll admit that this is **most** of the solution, but there is a missing part. I haven't done much programming in Powerpoint, so it was a challenge. When you open the VBE, there are no modules, classes, or objects of any kind available. This is quite different from Word and Excel. This means we're all on our own...

I created a Presentation with five slides. On the third slide, I inserted some objects so it looked like this:

[image]

For the VBA part, the first thing I had to learn was to create a [class module that will catch all of the events for the presentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa211599(v=office.11)). My very simple class is called `EventClassModule` and looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_SlideShowNextSlide(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    If Wn.View.CurrentShowPosition = 3 Then
        UpdateTheCount Wn.View.Slide
    End If
End Sub
```

So now in a regular module, you have to run something to create and initialize this class as a global object.

```
Option Explicit

Dim eventClass As EventClassModule

Sub InitializeApp()
    Set eventClass = New EventClassModule
    Set eventClass.App = Application
End Sub
```

In my testing, I just manually ran the `InitializeApp` procedure to create the global object. ***This is the missing part of my solution... - I don't know how to automatically run this initialization to create the object. Maybe a ribbon button?***

Then, also in the regular code module is the procedure to update the textbox:

```
Public Sub UpdateTheCount(ByRef thisSlide As Slide)
    '--- loop through all the shapes to find the correct textbox,
    '    then update the value for display
    Const LABEL_TEXT As String = "Value to update:"
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In thisSlide.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
            Dim theText As String
            theText = shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
            If InStr(1, theText, LABEL_TEXT, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                Dim colonPos As Long
                Dim theValue As Long
                colonPos = InStr(1, theText, ":", vbTextCompare)
                theValue = CLng(Right$(theText, Len(theText) - colonPos))
                theValue = theValue + 1
                theText = LABEL_TEXT & " " & theValue
                shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = theText
            End If
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Once your code is in place and you've run the `InitializeApp()` sub manually, just start the slide show (and probably set it to loop from the end) and step through it. The textbox value will update and increment automatically.

I'm interested in learning how to kick this off automatically from someone who's got that experience.

Comment: I should add that I tried to make the class persistent (`PredeclaredID=True`), and it crashed my PowerPoint when I reopened it. There may have been another issue, but I didn't find it.

Comment: This looks very interesting.  I'll check it out.

Comment: @PeterT Re: "When you open the VBE, there are no modules, classes, or objects of any kind available" Intellisense will help, or as with the other Office apps' VBE, press F2 to see the Object Browser, which lists PPT's own classes etc. Of course there *are* no modules until you've added them the current open file's project or to projects in other open files. You can't see modules/classes that are in add-ins unless you modify the registry.

Comment: If you save PeterT's code as an Add-in, you can include an Auto_Open subroutine; this will automatically run when the add-in loads (at PPT startup, once you've installed the add-in). Re making all of this run periodically, it might be simpler to write the update code as a VBScript or even an EXE that uses COM to drive PowerPoint, then set up the Windows scheduler to launch the script/EXE once a day.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg... thanks!  that's the real answer for the missing part. I should have thought about the add-in solution.

Comment: @PeterT  You know what they say: To a man with a hammer, every problem looks like a nail.  I write add-ins.  And sometimes the problem really IS a nail ;-)